# How do I parse a value with Storybook AddOns optionsKnob

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm building a Storybook for a client, and I want to dynamically change the color theme of components with the use of radio buttons. I've been following the docs, and this is how my code looks:

```js
import { withKnobs, optionsKnob as options } from '@storybook/addon-knobs'

const label = 'Theme color';
const valuesObj = {
  Red: 'red',
  Blue: 'blue',
  Purple: 'purple',
  Green: 'green'
};
const defaultValue = 'red';

const optionsObj = {
  display: 'inline-radio'
};

const groupId = '';

const themeValue = options(label, valuesObj, defaultValue, optionsObj, groupId);
```

This will display the correct inline radio buttons as intended, but as soon as I click on another radio, the inline buttons will disappear. I also tried to console.log the `themeValue`, and initially, it shows my default value (red), but it does not change on clicking on another value.

[image: Storybook Radios theme color]

I've been searching through the documentation, and I can only find how to [implement](https://openbase.io/js/@storybook/addon-knobs) it, but not how to parse / actually use the value. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The link you've added is actually the `@storybook/addon-knobs` [README](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/knobs#with-react) from GitHub. Did you see [this example](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/knobs#with-react) for React? It uses a `boolean` knob type, but it should be the same idea for `options`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, well, a colleague of mine did.

Instead of doing this:

```js
const themeValue = options(label, valuesObj, defaultValue, optionsObj, groupId);
```

I'm now doing this in my React component:

```js
<ExampleComponent theme={options(label, valuesObj, defaultValue, optionsObj, groupId)} />
```

Problem solved!